# Online quiz with slightly different questions for each student

Tags: online-instruction

I am looking for an online quiz that can generate multiple versions of a multiple choice question. What I want is:

- The same question can have a different text for each student
- Alternatives are randomized and picked from a larger pool (the student sees 5 alternatives, 1 correct, but I provided 10, 2 correct, and the software chose)
- Cloud based (so that I do not have to maintain a system running)

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: Such things certainly exist. My university has a platform for supporting its classes that offers facilities to produce quizzes more or less as you describe. It is propietary software contracted by the university, and the resulting quizzes are available only to the students and the instructor, not to the public, as the platform is closed to the public.

Comment: @DanFox  Would you mind sharing more about this platform? I need something like what you described.

Answer (score 4):

My institute is using this system: http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~OKUSON/ While it takes some time to understand how to use it  - and it is sometimes a little annoying, as it was written by Mathematicians who needed something for their exercises, not by Computer Scientists aiming to sell a perfect product - it can do what you want and it is free and open source.

Answer (score 4):

[WeBWorK](http://webwork.maa.org) of course

> WeBWorK is an open-source online homework system for math and sciences courses. WeBWorK is supported by the MAA and the NSF and comes with a National Problem Library (NPL) of over 20,000 homework problems. Problems in the NPL target most lower division undergraduate math courses and some advanced courses. Supported courses include college algebra, discrete mathematics, probability and statistics, single and multivariable calculus, differential equations, linear algebra and complex analysis.